# boost::this_thread::sleep() returns immediately

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

I'm working with a very simply boost sample on Windows, and I'm running into several strange issues.

Here's the program:

```
// BoostThreadTest.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#define BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>

void workerFunc()
{
    boost::posix_time::seconds workTime(3);
    std::cout << "Worker: running" << std::endl;

    boost::this_thread::sleep(workTime);

    std::cout << "Worker: finished" << std::endl;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "main: startup" << std::endl;

    boost::thread workerThread(workerFunc);

    std::cout << "main: waiting for thread" << std::endl;

    boost::posix_time::seconds workTime(10);
    boost::this_thread::sleep(workTime);
    //workerThread.join();

    std::cout << "main: done" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The main issue is that the `boost::this_thread::sleep` call in the `workerFunc` is not actually sleeping, it is returning immediately. I also get a generic exception in the debugger when I attempt to join with the thread. The really strange thing is that a call to `boost::this_thread::sleep` in the main method works fine!

Does anyone have any clue what the issue might be?

I am on Windows 7, using boost 1_53_0. I built the boost thread library as a static library and am linking it in with my application built using Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: What exception do you get exactly? FWIW, it works well on Win7x64, MSVC10. I see you disable auto-linking - perhaps you link with an incorrect Boost.Thread binary and get some ODR violation?

Comment: I guess I once experienced this issue after I upgraded my boost to version 1.53. In this version the 'sleep' function is deprecated and you should use 'sleep_for' or 'sleep_until' (And they use 'chrono' library for time, not posix_time).

Comment: Note that there has been a problem with a static variable in steady_clock::now(), which caused boost::chrono::sleep_for() to return immediately. This is fixed in Boost 1.56. See https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/9720